# Is there any way to tell if a variable was optimized out?

Tags: assembly, memory, fortran, heap-memory, stack-memory

I had some fortran code that looked something like:

```
 subroutine foo(mx,my,mz)
    real pts(3,mx,my,mz)
 end
```

the array pts was never actually used in the subroutine -- I just forgot to delete it when I refactored my code.  Now, since fortran has no concept of stack vs. heap, It's up to the compiler where to allocate pts -- This is a function of the array size in gfortran, but I haven't been able to figure out how the portland group compiler handles this.

Is it possible to tell whether pts is allocated on the stack, heap, or if it is completely optimized out altogether (as it probably should be)?  Is it possible to have a stackoverflow and not know it (i.e. not have a runtime error)?  My instinct is that it should be possible to tell by looking at the assembly produced by the compiler, but I have no clue what I'd be looking at there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to look at the assembly code that the compiler provides when you compile with `-S` or to look for symbols with the debugger. If the array is allocated on the heap, there will most probably be a call to the allocation function:

- **gfortran** inserts calls to `malloc`
- **ifort** by default allocates all arrays on the stack. If you enable automatic heap arrays by `-heap-arrays <size>` it will generate calls to `for_alloc` for heap allocation
- **PGI** compilers generate calls to `pgf90_auto_alloc` but I have no experience with this compiler and the way it allocates arrays

By the way, **gfortran** drops the array when it is not referenced even with the default optimisation level. I would guess the other compilers do the same but I won't bet on it.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is highly compiler-specific question in a sense that behavior related to dead-code elimination is not universal, and is not only compiler-specific but also case-specific. Modern compilers with optimizations turned on definitely eliminate all unreachable code, or code which achieves nothing in terms of the state of the program. Unused variables and arrays do not end up at all in the final executable.

As you mentioned, your best bet is to look at the assembly code of the compiled binary and see what it does.